# How to add to column to a data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say you have dataframe df

```
 ID     data 
1  1234    123     
2  1234    213     
3  1234    432   
4  1234    32     
5  1234    54     
6  5678    67
```

And you want to add a new column called 'calculation' which returns a fucntion:
data[1]-data[0]/data[0] (as we need data from the previous cell the first cell of 'calculation' would be 0)

How do we add this column an how can we write this function that takes in values that aren't on the same row where the data is being stored ?

Answer (score 2):

You merely can find the relative difference, then impute a 0:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'data': range(5)
})

df['calc'] = (df.data.shift(1) - df.data) / df.data
df.calc.values[0] = 0

>>> df
    data    calc
0   0   0
1   1   -1.000000
2   2   -0.500000
3   3   -0.333333
4   4   -0.250000

5 rows × 2 columns
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case you mentioned, you'd use a `diff`.  For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[123, 312, 432, 32, 54, 67]})
df['new'] = df['data'].diff() / df['data']
```

Which yields:

```
   data        new
0   123        NaN
1   312   0.605769
2   432   0.277778
3    32 -12.500000
4    54   0.407407
5    67   0.194030
```

In general, though, these types of things are vectorization tricks.  Shifting and slicing can be very useful.  For example, say we wanted

```
(data[i] + data[i+1]) / data[i]
```

If you're familiar with numpy arrays, you would probably try:

```
df['new'] = (df['data'][:-1] + df['data'][1:]) / df['data']
```

Because of the way `pandas` handles automatic alignment, this result will be slightly different than our previous one:

```
   data  new
0   123  NaN
1   312    2
2   432    2
3    32    2
4    54    2
5    67  NaN
```

Therefore, with `pandas` it's  better to explicitly shift the sequence instead of using slicing, in this case:

```
df['new'] = (df['data'].shift(1) + df['data']) / df['data'].astype(float)
```

This yields:

```
   data        new
0   123        NaN
1   312   1.394231
2   432   1.722222
3    32  14.500000
4    54   1.592593
5    67   1.805970
```